# How to read data from multiple Excel files with Informatica

Tags: excel, loops, foreach, informatica-powercenter

I have data in multiple Excel files and all my Excel files are placed in the same folder. I want to read data from multiple Excel files and load the data into a Oracle destination table. How can I achieve this using Informatica PowerCenter?

This is a very similar example done using  [SSIS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4165/how-to-read-data-from-multiple-excel-files-with-sql-server-integration-services/).

Answer (score 0):

Please share the details of which OS  your Powercenter client is installed and also the version of informatica..?

This is possible however a bit tricky..

Comment: OS: Windows 7 x64
Informatica: Designer Version 9.5.1

Comment: @maggie indirect files wont work here because Informatica reads  excels as ODBC connections.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve the same result.
You have only mentioned the client OS.... not the server OS.

Since your Q is very vague... i'll post it for Win OS.

From my experience, I would say, select the "indirect load" .
Create a new text file and list all the excel files which you want to load.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and hassle free way is to convert the excels to csv files.

If your Informatica server is installed in windows, it is recommended to use a VB/powershell script to convert the file to CSV and then use indirect file load. If the informatica server is installed in linux  then you have to use a perl script to convert the file to csv. Reading multiple excel files directly is a very cumbersome effort  and will have a lot of challenges.

[Powershell convert excel to csv](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3223/extract-and-convert-all-excel-worksheets-into-csv-files-using-powershell/)  . 
There are various solution in internet and Stack overflow to convert excel to csv in linux

Answer (score 0):

Informatica uses ODBC to read Excel files. The file needs to have a Named Range defined. This - unless already defined in your source files - makes it a huge problem. Big enough to have the Excel files converted to csv with some external script - and then loading it as a list of files (via indirect load mentioned by @maggie).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ODBC driver to read the excel file. If you have multiple file with same structure. I will suggest you to follow below approach:

1. Change the file into .csv by using suitable scripting language (perl ,python).
   2.use indirect file load method. you can give file names in a separate file.
   this way you can process all files in one go.

Hope this helps.